# PtQt5 QComboBox при выборе одного варианта меняются значения в QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qtablewidget, qcombobox

Помогите, пожалуйста, с реализацией задачи, чтобы при выборе одного из вариантов из `QComboBox` менялись значения в ячейках таблицы `QTableWidget`.

Приложил скриншот формы. Красным пером выделены объекты моего вопроса.

[image: Пример формы(красным пером выделено то, что должно изменяться)]

Comment: Покажите приме, который у вас есть. Не понятно где у вас находится  `QComboBox ` и в каких ячейках должны изменится значения?.

Comment: @S.Nick добавил скриншот формы. Кода пока нету, ибо не знаю с чего начать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начните с изучения небольшого примера

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QApplication, QTableWidget, 
    QTableWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout, QComboBox, QMessageBox)
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(4)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        for i in range(4):
            for j in range(2):
                item = QTableWidgetItem("Item {}-{}".format(i, j))
                item.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
                self.tableWidget.setItem(i, j, item)

        self._list = [
                       'Изменить: row: 0, column: 0',
                       'Изменить: row: 1, column: 0',
                       'Изменить: row: 2, column: 0',
                       'Изменить: row: 3, column: 0',
                     ]
        self.combobox = QComboBox()
        self.combobox.addItems(self._list)
        self.combobox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.on_combobox_func)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self) 
        self.layout.addWidget(self.combobox)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget) 

    def on_combobox_func(self, index):     
        item = QTableWidgetItem("{}".format(self.combobox.currentText()))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(index, 0, item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Example()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отлично, только вот нужно чтобы изменялась не только одна ячейка и значения не совпадали с текстом QComboBox.. Было бы хорошо, если бы вы добавили # с небольшим объяснением. Надеюсь, я не много прошу.

Comment: @AdmiralOwl я вам с удовольствием объясню, что вам будет не понятно, но после прочтения  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html и https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html